# sklearn, scoring of ExtraTreesClassifier confused

Tags: scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I have 2 imbalanced classes , 50 000 samples and positives occurs %5 in the set. Data is 2 dimensional.

Issue is, I'm using **ExtraTreesClassifier**. **oob_score_** looks OK, but when I examine the **f1 score** with ***cross_validation.cross_val_score*** , I get low values. I'm totally confused my classifier is OK or rubbish.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
trees = ExtraTreesClassifier(bootstrap=true, oob_score=True,n_estimators=100,class_weight="auto")

for i in range(1, 101):
    trees.set_params(n_estimators=i)    
    trees.fit(x,y)
    print trees.oob_score_
```

It prints
    0.919955
    0.919353
    0.919353
... increasing.

When I do a

```
from sklearn import cross_validation as cval
cv = cval.StratifiedKFold(y, 2)
cval.cross_val_score(trees, x, y, scoring="f1", cv=cv)
```

result is 
    *array([ 0.01604747,  0.01250169])* 
, which is pretty bad.

Can someone enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The out of bag scoring metric is the accuracy. Given the imbalance in your data, the result is normal.

There is a stalled pull request to allow choosing the scoring metrics
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3723

For now, you can still compute the oob f1-score using the [oob_decision_score_](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier) attributes.